# CSS / HTML centering a textbox

Tags: css

This should be easy but its proving difficult...

My element I want centred is exactly this `<input type="text">`

I don't want the text centred, just the text box within the outer div.

This is my attempt which is not working

```
<div class ="temp123">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Where:

```
.temp123
{
margin: 0 auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

The text box remains on the left.

The outer div has a fixed with of 300px and itself is centered using `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.temp123{
  text-align:center;
}
.temp123 > input{
  text-align:left;
}
```

or simply (but not tested):

```
.temp123 > input{
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: The latter didn't work but your first suggestion worked a treat!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm not getting the question but this should do it.

```
<style>
.temp123
{
margin: 0 auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
<div class ="temp123">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your CSS you're selecting the div's margin, the space outside the div.

You'll need to select it like `.temp123 input {...}`

Hope that helps.