# Centering a textbox in HTML

Tags: css, html, input, textbox

I am making a website and I am trying to center a text box on my website. I tried everything and nothing seems to work. I need to have it centered so it looks good on the mobile view as well.

I looked at this thread

[CSS / HTML centering a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005119/css-html-centering-a-textbox)

And I tried the solutions in it, but nothing worked.

Here is my code for the text box that I am trying to center. Please keep in mind I am not trying to center the text inside, I want the entire text box centered.

```
.imgUrlText
{
    font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
}

<input type = "text" class = "imgUrlText" size = "70" id = "urlText" placeholder = "Image Url">
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in multiple ways.

**With a fixed width of the textbox:**

```css
.imgUrlText {
  font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="imgUrlText" size="70" id="urlText" placeholder="Image Url">
```

**Not with a fixed width of the textbox:**

Wrap a `div` around with `text-align: center;`.

```css
.aligncenter {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.imgUrlText {
  font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="aligncenter">
<input type="text" class="imgUrlText" size="70" id="urlText" placeholder="Image Url">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it within the html by putting center tags around it like so:

```
 <center><input type = "text" class = "imgUrlText" size = "70" id = "urlText" placeholder = "Image Url"></center>
```

But that could be a rather inefficient method if you have multiple input boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way.

```
.imgUrlText {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3e8bxhmg/

Don't use `<center>` this is depreciated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 0):

```css
.imgDiv {
    width:400px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #A12A1E;
    color:White;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.imgDiv > div {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:250px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    margin:10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgDiv">
  <div>
<input type = "text"  size = "30" id = "urlText" placeholder = "Image Url">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers that support CSS 3 you can do an easy centering using these three lines of code:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

The magic trick is in the `transform: translatex(-50%);` part.
Usual CSS positions your element at the top left corner of the box.
The translate now subtracts the element's width from this position which leads to a centering of the element since `left: 50%` is the horizontal center of the viewport.
`position: absolute` is required for it to work! 
Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SUBHUMAN/kdb6shs2/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a div with text align center:

```css
.imgUrlText
{
    font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">


<input type = "text" class = "imgUrlText" size = "70" id = "urlText" placeholder = "Image Url">

</div>
```